# What function to use in excel if I would like to sum the cells in which the rows contains the word "confirmed"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to ask if I have cell (A1 to A10) in numbers and the rest of the rows in text that contains

> "confirmed",
>    "confirmed-ALS",
>    "confirmed-lead".

How do I sum up the cells (A1 to A10) for those cells that contain the text *confirmed*.

I have this - `=IF((C6:Q6)="*Confirmed*", SUM(C3:Q3), "")`, but it seems wrong.. hope someone can help..

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

from your question i think you want

```
=SUMIF(C6:Q6,"confirmed*",C3:Q3)
```